# HTML tables in content areas

Tags: html, content, formatting, table, html-editor

Is there a plugin that would allow me to create and edit tables within the content block in posts and pages? I suppose a bit like the 'insert table' command in MS Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick Google search and it took me to this [article](http://bloggingwithsuccess.net/add-manage-tables-wordpress-posts/).
I have not used either of the plugins mentioned but they are [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) and [WP-Table Reloaded](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-table-reloaded/) hopefully one of those work out for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Tinymce advanced lets you do this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)